# vaadin 7: Widgetset does not contain implementation

Tags: vaadin

I am trying my hands on vaadin and would like to use gantt chat add-on in my vaading 7 project.
https://vaadin.com/directory#addon/vaadin-gantt-diagram:vaadin

since this is not compatible with vaadin 7, I am trying to fix some code from the add-on to make it compatible with vaadin 7.

I checked out source code of vaadin-6.8 from repository and vaadin-gantt (add-on) from available downloads.

I changed the code a bit in vaadin-6.8 and built. I am using this customized vaadin-6.8 jar inside vaadin-gantt add-on. Now I am able to build vaadin-gantt add-on by using customized vaadin-6.8 jar. I want to use this add-on inside vaadin-7 project.

compiling went through, but i am getting below message on console while displaying gantt chart

**"Widgetset does not contain implementation for ru.bazon.vaadin.ganttdiagram.canvas.GanttDiagramCanvas. Check its component connector's @Connect mapping, widgetsets GWT module description file and re-compile your widgetset. In case you have downloaded a vaadin add-on package, you might want to refer to add-on instructions."**

I compiled the gantt widgetset using eclipse plugin and could see the below entry in my projects *.gwt.xml file

I would like to make use of gannt chart add-on for vaadin-7. I didn't find any other add-on for vaadin-7 apart from this which is not compatible with vaadin 7.

any pointers?

Regards,
Azhar

Comment: You have to convert the add-on for Vaadin 7, your approach with customized Vaadin 6.8 won't work.

Comment: Agree with Henri. There has been lot of changes for Widgetset from 6.8.8 to Vaadin 7. Changes include use of Shared State, Client and Server RPC

Answer (score 6):

Please make sure You have added **@Widgetset("path of *.gwt.xml")** on your main UI class.I have solved by adding this

Comment: Find the package containing the ".gwt.xml" file (ex: "com.mycompany.ui.AppWidgetSet.gwt.xml"), then add the class name to the annotation minus the '.gwt.xml" ex: @Widgetset("com.mycompany.ui.AppWidgetSet")  Then make sure you do a Vaadin compile as well.

Answer (score 3):

I just had this error as well and it was caused by missing source files in the addon jar. Both .java and .class files must be present in the addon jar file as GWT compiles from sources. But most likely the addons form vaadin directory should include also the sources. And ofcourse don't forget to compile the widgetset and themes after importing your addon to your project.

Comment: I have been searched the error for more as two days. For all which using gradle: Add to your Widget project the following to the "jar" task for putting the Java source files together with the class files into the jar file: `from sourceSets.main.allSource`

Answer (score 2):

Just leaving this here in case someone has the same case as I had. Our project is in Vaadin 8, and we already had `@Widgetset("com.company.OurWidgetSet")` as annotation on our `UI`-extending class.

However, I still received the same error as OP when accessing a pop-up of a separated component. Although we did try to migrate this component of ours to Vaadin 8 in the past, due to lack of time to do this properly, it was still mostly using Vaadin7 imports and functionality.

Because of this I had to add the following to our `OurWidgetSet.gwt.xml` file (within the `<module>`-tag) in our main project, to fix the functionality of the used component:

```
<inherits name="com.vaadin.v7.Vaadin7WidgetSet" />
```

Answer (score 1):

just had the same issue as well, another thing to make sure if you use vaadin is the web.xml inside the WEB-INF folder of deployed resources.
Make sure the widgetset is also specified there:

```
<init-param>
<description>AWidgetSet</description>
<param-name>widgetset</param-name>
<param-value>com.example.a.widgetset.AWidgetset</param-value>
</init-param>
```

Answer (score 0):

When using Java Config with Annotation @VaadinServletConfiguration an additional Solution is to add this as Annotation-Parameter **widgetset**:

```
@VaadinServletConfiguration(ui = MyUI.class, productionMode = true, heartbeatInterval = 500, closeIdleSessions = true, widgetset = "com.myapp.MyWidgetset")
```